# trying to implement facebook and google plus icon in my website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, google-plus

For face book and Google Plus I am getting 407 and 403 result code. I used the below URL for generating  face book  share and Google plus icon

http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Can someone suggest me what I am missing

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 18:20:17 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 4
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1

Message: Permission denied
Line: 1
Char: 8164
Code: 0
URI: https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1324331373.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are Liking or plus 1'ing probably is not accessible to the linters being used (meaning it is not a public URL).  For facebook you can quickly determine the status of your URL by linting it at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: Google's version of the linter is http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets